# Define union of parametrized class

Tags: c++, templates

I have this simple class:

```
template<int N>
struct Conn {
    int value; //let type be `int` for simplicity
};
```

I need to define class "AnyConn" with arbitrary parameter.
Something like this: (doesn't work)

```
typedef (template<int N> Conne) AnyConn;
```

or like this: (also doesn't work)

```
struct AnyConn {
    template<int N> Conne d;
};
```

.

I need to hide parameter N, make it "arbitrary", such that Conn<0>, Conn<12> and Conn<33> may be packed as AnyConn.
How to do that in a right and type-safe way?

Comment: Maybe you can have a base class that actually contains the `int`, which all `Conn` class inherits from. `Conn<0>` is completely unrelated to `Conn<1>` so you need to establish some sort of relation explicitly. But It's not clear what you want to achieve here. There may be way better solutions than this.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What operations does `AnyConn` need to support and what should be their semantics? For example, would @FrançoisAndrieux's proposed solution work? If not, why not?

Comment: @Brian . I have different definitions for several specific N and an empty struct for other N. I need class that can hold them all. It is like union {Conn<0> a; Conn<1> a; ... }; . Maybe it is not possible, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::any`, which can hold any copyable object type, to implement something that can hold only some types:

```
class AnyConn {
  public:
    template <int N>
    AnyConn(Conn<N> conn) : tag_(N), storage_(conn) {}

    int tag() const { return tag_; }

    template <int N> Conn<N>* get() { return std::any_cast<Conn<N>>(&storage_); }
    template <int N> const Conn<N>* get() const { return std::any_cast<Conn<N>>(&storage_); }

  private:
    int tag_;
    std::any storage_;
};
```

You may need to modify this approach depending on your specific requirements, but in general some form of `std::any` will do the job.

Comment: What is your opinion, is it possible to do it without casting?

Comment: @ged If you don't perform some kind of cast, then how will you know whether the object contained is of the correct type (has the correct N)? You said that you wanted a type-safe solution.

Comment: So, that means that C++'s type system cannot respresent union of family of types. As for me it's a little bit strange because compiler can check every implemented instance and determine maximal size of structure. it seems works, so worth upwotes, but it is not exactly what i'm looking for...

Comment: @ged I don't understand your requirements. Unions do exist in C++, and the solution I wrote should be able to do most things that you could do with a finite union.

Comment: Now I see that my requirement may be reformulated  as "Sigma-type" or "dependent sum" in C++.

Comment: @ged C++ doesn't have a dependent type system. You can have dependent types (in this case the type stored inside `AnyConn` depends on the tag) but there is no dependent type checking at compile time so for example you cannot extract the `Conn<N>` object with run-time value `N` from the `AnyConn` and then expect the compiler to check the validity of any further operations for all possible `N`.